# why compilation fails when import "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake"

Tags: go, kubernetes

Getting compilation error when try to use kubernetes/fake from "production" code.
however when create test and use fake from there only then everything is good and test compilation is not failing.

compilation error:

> cmd\test\test.go:3:8: cannot find package

project structure

```
awesomeProject
│   go.mod
│   go.sum
└───cmd
    └───test
            test.go
```

here is test.go

```
package main

import "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake"

func main() {
    clientset := fake.NewSimpleClientset()
    print(clientset)
}
```

here is go.mod (updated to have same version of api + goclient)

```
module awesomeProject

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/evanphx/json-patch v4.5.0+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/googleapis/gnostic v0.4.1 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20200420201142-3c4aac89819a // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200421231249-e086a090c8fd // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20200107190931-bf48bf16ab8d // indirect
    golang.org/x/time v0.0.0-20200416051211-89c76fbcd5d1 // indirect
    k8s.io/api v0.18.2 // indirect
    k8s.io/client-go v0.18.2 // indirect
    k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20200414100711-2df71ebbae66 // indirect
)
```

This question is coming from need to move kubernetes/fake related code to separate package from test code.

Comment: You might have to use the same version of go module for client, utils and api by defining them all yourself. My guess: v0.18.2 for all should work

Comment: just tried still having the same issue